# iterating over a table passed as an argument to a function in lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, iterator, lua-table

I am trying using the `for _ in pairs()` notation to iterate over a table within a function, but if I type anything, even gibberish like `print('asdgfafs')`, nested inside the for loop, it never gets printed. Code:

```
record = {bid1,bid2,bid3}
bid1 = {bidTime = 0.05,bidType = 'native'}
bid2 = {bidTime = 0.1,bidType = 'notNative'}
bid3 = {bidTime = 0.3,bidType = 'native'}

function getBids(rec,bidTimeStart,bidTimeFinish,bidType,numberOfBids)
    wantedBids = {}
    bidCount = 0

    for i,v in pairs(rec) do
        print('asdfasdfasdfa')
        print(i .. ' + ' .. v)
    end
end

getBids(record,0,1,'native',5)
```

Can anyone tell me why and suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `record` table *before* creating the `bid#` tables.

So when you do `record = {bid1, bid2, bid3}` none of the `bid#` variables have been created yet and so they are all `nil`. So that line is effectively `record = {nil, nil, nil}` which, obviously, doesn't give the `record` table any values.

Invert those lines to put the `record` assignment *after* the `bid#` variable creation.

Comment: I'm such a moron.. been working with node.js all week you see, I forgot that other languages weren't asynchronous! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with synchronous or asynchronous. This exact code pattern in node.js would fail as well. You cannot use a variable before you define it. In javascript however all variable definitions are hoisted so `var x; code1; var y; code2; var z` actually defines all the variables at the start of the block. If you add `local record, bid1, bid2, bid3` to the top of this snippet it'll work too for exactly the same reason. Alternatively, leave `var` out of the javascript and it might fail (though declared variable hoisting might even happen implicitly, I don't recall offhand).

Comment: Oh, I just assumed there was no equivalent of javascript's var in lua? So is local the equivalent of javascript's var?

Comment: Not exactly, but sort of.

Comment: If you want to keep the order like that, initialize `record` as an empty table, but alter the `bid#` to `record.bid#` for example. Regarding to the question about `local` in Lua, it is not exactly the same as `var` in js, but you _should_ use `local` pretty much everywhere unless you really need to "pollute" the global space. Using `local` will restrict the scope of the variable, but you can define them beforehand and use them as upvalues later, or make use of tables to widen their scope.

Comment: @lyravega What was your point about that keeping the order business? The way the OP's code is written (with pre-defined locals) has the bids in-order in the table already.